# mktime argument out of range

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-python

I am using azure-sdk for python specifically azure-servicebus 0.50.0

```
from azure.servicebus import QueueClient
service_bus_queue_connectionString= "my service bus string"
service_bus_queue_name ="service bus queue"
queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(service_bus_queue_connectionString, service_bus_queue_name)
sessions= queue_client.list_sessions() print(sessions)
```

While using the following code ,i am getting the following error

> An exception of type OverflowError occurred. Arguments: ('mktime
>   argument out of range',)

What could be the possible reason?

EDIT 
Please find the stack trace . Any help would be appreciated.

```
File "C:\Users\NewtonCode\Desktop\EY.TPBML.PY - Copy\model_engine.py", line 28, in start_process
    sessions = self.queue_client.list_sessions()
  File "C:\Users\NewtonCode\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\servicebus\servicebus_client.py", line 469, in list_sessions
    mgmt_handlers.list_sessions_op)
  File "C:\Users\NewtonCode\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\servicebus\base_handler.py", line 83, in _mgmt_request_response
    **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\NewtonCode\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uamqp\message.py", line 109, in __init__
    self._body.set(body)
  File "C:\Users\NewtonCode\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uamqp\message.py", line 913, in set
    value = utils.data_factory(value)
  File "C:\Users\NewtonCode\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uamqp\utils.py", line 108, in data_factory
    wrapped_dict[data_factory(key, encoding=encoding)] = data_factory(item, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\NewtonCode\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uamqp\utils.py", line 117, in data_factory
    timestamp = int((time.mktime(value.utctimetuple()) * 1000) + (value.microsecond/1000))
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. Also check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CristiFati I have posted the stacktrace. Could you please give me some insights?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for raising this issue - it looks like a bug in the library.

While not a solution - I have opened an issue in the underlying uAMQP library here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-python/issues/63

In the meantime, you can potentially work around this by passing in an "updated-since" timestamp into the list_sessions operation:

```
# Start time of a week ago - replace with appropriate value
start_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
sessions = queue_client.list_sessions(updated_since=start_time)
```

Thanks again, I will try to publish a fix asap! :)

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, but I didn't get into the source code :)

Comment: Thanks @Anna , I have tried your suggestion . The error has vanished but I still get empty session list.

Comment: Hi @NewtonCode, the list_sessions operation will only return sessions that have had a state assigned to them. So simply sending messages to a new session will not mean that session ID is listed. Sessions that have had the state set within the specified "updated_since" timestamp *should* be returned in the list operation.